# issue with update file in azure data lake store using rest api

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-lake

i'm trying to get data from local file and add data into one of the file into adls(azure data lake store) i'm following the below URL.
[click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update#code-try-0)

how can i pass parameters and body to the api using c# because so many headers don't have any value

below code i tried to execute but no success.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        {
            String storageAccountUrl = "https://XXXXXXXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net/XXXXX/test.txt?action=flush&position=0&retainUncommittedData=false&close=true";
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationToken);
            var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PutAsync(storageAccountUrl, new StringContent("test"));
            string resp = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
```

how should i pass other headers and is it the right way to pass body.

Comment: Is this adls gen2?

Comment: yes i'm using adls gen2 using rest api

Comment: Please show relevant code of what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is working fine if update a empty file:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var auth = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();          

            const string url = "https://storage.azure.com/";
            string token = auth.GetAccessTokenAsync(url).Result;
            string requestUri = "https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/t11/c.txt?action=append&position=0";
            var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");

            string upload_string = "have a nice day!";

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(upload_string)
            };

            // Add some defined headers
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
            var i = request.Content.AsString().Length;
            Console.WriteLine(request.Content.AsString());

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var result = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

            Console.WriteLine("append result status code: "+ (int)result.StatusCode);

            //for flush    
            string requestUri_2 = "https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/t11/c.txt?action=flush&position="+upload_string.Length;

            var request_2 = new HttpRequestMessage(method,requestUri_2);

            using (HttpClient httpClient_2 = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient_2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient_2.SendAsync(request_2).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("flush result status code: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
            }

          Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation, some headers are just optional which means that you do not need to set them in the headers.  You only need to set the required headers.

**Update:**

For how to use Httpclient to send a patch request in C#, you may get a lot of samples and documentations on the internet. Here is just a sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string requestUri = "the uri, https://.....";
    var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri)
    {
        Content = new StringContent("Test string")
    };

    // Add some defined headers
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // Add some other headers or custom headers
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("custome_header", "value");

    var hc = new HttpClient();
    var result = hc.SendAsync(request).Result;

    Console.WriteLine(result);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: yes but the parameters like x-ms-lease-id,x-ms-client-request-id,x-ms-date,x-ms-version required and how to pass those parameters and body in c# as i'm using httpClient.

Comment: thanks @jack for your comment but still i'm getting some issue as below                    **The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.** do we have to add any other headers?

Comment: @MBG I am not sure. If you can share more detailed information, maybe I can do more help on this. The API you used, and the code snippet.